# Django url tag gives wrong values

Tags: django

My URLconf has:

```
url(r'^view-item$', 'appname.views.view_item', name='view-item'),
```

Now, if I go to `http://myhost/path_to_django_app/view-item/`, it works.  However, `{% url view-item %}` returns '/view-item/'.  Why is it doing this?

This problem occurred when I moved the application to a new server, so I'm guessing something must be configured wrong, but I don't even know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be due to the `SCRIPT_NAME` variable not being set correctly. The `url` tag will use this variable to compose the final absolute path to return.

You should check what `request.META['SCRIPT_NAME']` is set to in one of your views. If it is not set correctly, then you may need to look into your backend configuration. If you are using mod_python, this usually involves making sure that django.root is set in the apache config. Check the installation docs for [more info](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/).

If you still can't get it to work, you can try adding this to settings.py:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/path_to_django_app/'
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual way to write your URl in django is with a trailing '/':

```
url(r'^view-item/$', 'appname.views.view_item', name='view-item')
```

or:

```
url(r'^view-item/', include('view.urls')),
```

Life will be much easier if you follow this convention.